# How to store log file in console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using Asp.net core 3.1 and trying to save log file. I am able to store a log file in web application  by adding "loggerFactory.AddFile("/Logs/mylog-{Date}.txt");" into the startup.cs file but I am not able to store log file in the console application.

```
class Program
    {
        //public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        private static AppDbContext _context;
        private static IServiceProvider _service;
        public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;
        public static IOptions<ServiceEndpoint> _endpoint;
        private static ILogger<CallService> _logger;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                var services = new ServiceCollection();
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory))
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);

                Configuration = builder.Build();

                services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
                
                services.AddLogging();
                
                using (var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole()))
                {
                    loggerFactory.AddFile("/Logs/mylog-{Date}.txt");
                }

                var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                }
                _logger.LogInformation("Process runnning");
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                _logger.LogError(ex.InnerException.ToString());
            }
              }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your code, I suppose you are using the `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` library to store the log information to a file, right? I have checked [its resource document](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file), but not find the article about how to use it in a console application. So, as a workaround, I suggest you could try to use the [Serilog library](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) to store the log information to a file.

To store log information in a console application, you could refer the following steps:

1. Install the `Serilog.Sinks.Console` and `Serilog.Sinks.Console` package via Nuget.
2. Creating a logger.

   ```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                 .WriteTo.File("log.txt")  // log file.
                 .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
                 .CreateLogger();
   ```

   sample code as below (add the `Serilog` and `Serilog.Events` namespaces):

   ```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                     .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                     .WriteTo.File("log.txt")
                     .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
                     .CreateLogger(); 
            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting up"); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
   ```

   More detail information about using `Serilog`, check the [Serilog Configuration Basics](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics).

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Is there any way I can use Loggerfactory instead of serilog?

Comment: I search lots of articles about using the Loggerfactory, but not found a workaround to use it in a console application, if you still want to use it (suppose you are using the `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` library), you could try to post this issue on the [Loggerfactory forum](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file).

Comment: Thank you Zhi Lv. With your solution I am able to see log in console but I still cannot save that log file. Do I need to pass path in WriteTo.File()?

Comment: @Neu check bin\Debug folder in directory where is your solution/project located.

Comment: Thank you @Anve I found it. Is there any way I can store it to any specific location?

Comment: @Neu just create file path and pass with file name to WriteTo.File method. Like this:
 ```string logFilePath = Path.Combine(LogDirectory, $"log_{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss")}.txt") ```
I put in log file name with date format to ensure unique name every time when you run application.

Comment: @anve it is not working. I have folder name Logs and I used it like :  string logFilePath = Path.Combine("logs\\", $"log_{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss")}.txt")

Comment: @Neu try like this Path.Combine("..\\logs", $"log_{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss")}.txt");

But this will also create logs folder inside Debug directory, If you want to create logs folder somewhere else provide full path to folder like this "C:\tmp\MyProject\"

Comment: @Anve thanks. I provided the full path and it worked.

Comment: @Neu, I suppose you have created a Logs folder in the Console application, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0kfL.png), then you could use this path: `.WriteTo.File("../../../Logs/log.txt")`. After executing the code, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C7bp.png).